# Best practice to prevent element manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How to solve problem of element manipulation for example on chrome. I have button that hide/disabled. Through chrome element, it allowed to change from hide/disabled into show/enabled. It can trigger my click function. Any best practice for this issues?

Comment: Not clear, give examples please

Comment: What harm will that cause ? Form submission ? DB operation ? If any of that kind, you have server side code to handle that. No one can edit that :P

Comment: function call. trigger when button is show..when element can be manipulate to make hide to show. So thats gonna be a problem

Comment: I really don't understand what do you mean? The fact, the user can manipulate the DOM with the Developertools, is a problem to you? I hope you don't manage security relevant stuff only on the client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent any manipulations on frontend. So you need store application state on backend and use this stored value to make decision about current logic of application.